# Developing for ASP.Net MVC, Visual Studio tab names are meaningless

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

For all Visual Studio ASP.Net MVC developers - I'm sure you've faced this problem before:

[image]

In each one of my controllers, there is usually an Index, Create, Edit and Detail views. All of the default view files generated by ASP.Net's scaffolding are all given the same name, for example: `index.cshtml`. Granted, they're in different folders.

So it's really easy to get lost in Visual Studio when you have four or five tabs open, all with the same name! Is there a way/plugin to get visual studio show me something more meaningful, such as the controller name/view folder? Or do you developers just rename all of your files once they're generated? I already have resharper so bonus points if it's possible with that.

Comment: When you hover with your mouse over a tab, you should be able to see the wanted information. If you were to show the full namespace on the tabs there wouldn't even be space enough to show them, so you'd have the same problem.

Comment: A plugin that could show an icon before the tab name based on the folder would be nice... maybe it's time to try my hand at plugin development.

Comment: Quoting Vojta Jína from AngularJS, "Take time to set up your environment. It's worth it in the long run.". Bradley, if you set up a Github/Visual studio online project I'll put in some work in it this weekend :)

Comment: I took some time to try and see what is possible as far as modifying the tab text.  From what I can find, it just isn't possible without completely re-implementing the existing tab system.  Unfortunately that's a bit more work that I'm willing to spend right now.  It's possible that I missed something,so if anyone else wants to have a go at it, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

FYI If you just hover over the tab, it tells you what View/Folder it is in.  That's one way to differentiate between the different tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e8ebfe4-023f-4c4d-9b7a-d05bbc5cb239 with VS2013 and VS Community 2015.

Comment: How does that help differentiate tabs?  It looks helpful for know what file you are currently in, but I don't see it helping to find a specific tab.

Comment: Yes, it's to identify the active file, it helps me. ;-) Ok, if you have three or more index.cshtml opened, it will be difficult. But I only work on one controller or two at a time, no more. See @coggicc answer

Comment: @BradleyUffner Take a look I think it allows you to specify an expression. Maybe we can do something like ({{parentFolderName}}\Filename).replace(".cshtml", "").  `Reply\Index` would be fantastic to be honest, but I don't have time to look at this plugin in detail. Of course that's only useful if it applies the expression to all tabs, which I'm not sure it does.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do so far is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> with resharper:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Productivity Power Tools extension has a custom document well that lets you color code the tabs.  It is usually used to color code them by the project they are in, but it also allows you to use custom regex.  You could disable the project based color coding and add custom regexes to color any document tab with "Edit" in the path Blue, and documents with "Create" Green, etc...   You will need to turn on the option for "Use full document path for regular expression matching" under the "advanced" tab of the power tool options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The VS add-in [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) works for me.

After installing open the *Tab Studio add-in manager* and select the Disambiguator add-in, i.e.: [image]

Will then give you tabs like this:

[image]

Note: it costs $49 after the 30 day trial...